# Mail sender validation error

Tags: email, validation

Using CiviCRM 4.7.31 / Joomla! 3.8.6 / PHP 5.6.33
After Upgrade from 4.7.29 to 4.7.31 it is not possible to send mails.
Test Mails do work

Error is obviously related to standard sender address, but adding another did not help.

Used Mail: "XXXXXXXX"

ERROR LOG

```
Mar 27 20:39:17  [info] Ignoring exception thrown by nullHandler: , Validation failed for: "&quot;XXXXXXXX&quot;" &lt;info@XXXXXXXX.de&gt;

Mar 27 20:39:17  [info] $backTrace = #0 /path/html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(962): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::nullHandler(Object(PEAR_Error))
#2 /path/html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(PEAR_Error))
#3 /path/html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(577): PEAR_Error->__construct("Validation failed for: \"&quot;XXXXXXXX&quot;\" &lt;info@XXXXXXXX.de&gt;", NULL, 16, (Array:2), NULL)
#4 [internal function](): PEAR::_raiseError(NULL, "Validation failed for: \"&quot;XXXXXXXX&quot;\" &lt;info@XXXXXXXX.de&gt;")
#5 /path/html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(237): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:2))
#6 /path/html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/Mail/RFC822.php(209): PEAR::__callStatic("raiseError", (Array:1))
#7 /path/html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/Mail/RFC822.php(209): PEAR::raiseError("Validation failed for: \"&quot;XXXXXXXX&quot;\" &lt;info@XXXXXXXX.de&gt;")
#8 /path/html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/Mail.php(191): Mail_RFC822->parseAddressList("\"&quot;XXXXXXXX&quot;\" &lt;info@XXXXXXXX.de&gt;", "localhost", FALSE)
#9 /path/html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/Mail/mail.php(151): Mail->prepareHeaders((Array:10))
#10 /path/html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Mail.php(292): Mail_mail->send((Array:1), (Array:12), "--=_044801405ebb4f44ee3cf939f827fbbc\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\nCont...")
#11 /path/html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/MessageTemplate.php(567): CRM_Utils_Mail::send((Array:17))
#12 /path/html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Task/Invoice.php(510): CRM_Core_BAO_MessageTemplate::sendTemplate((Array:9))
#13 /path/html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Task/Invoice.php(203): CRM_Contribute_Form_Task_Invoice::printPDF((Array:1), (Array:5), (Array:1))
#14 /path/html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(447): CRM_Contribute_Form_Task_Invoice->postProcess()
#15 /path/html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php(169): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#16 /path/html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php(136): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->realPerform(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Task_Invoice), "upload")
#17 /path/html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->perform(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Task_Invoice), "upload")
#18 /path/html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Task_Invoice), "upload")
#19 /path/html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("upload")
#20 /path/html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(113): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#21 /path/html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(283): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Contribute_Form_Task_Invoice", "Email Invoice", NULL)
#22 /path/html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))
#23 /path/html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
#24 /path/html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(121): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#25 /path/html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(40): civicrm_invoke()
#26 /path/html/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php(382): require_once("/path/html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")
#27 /path/html/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php(357): Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::executeComponent("/path/html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")
#28 /path/html/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php(101): Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")
#29 /path/html/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php(159): Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->dispatch()
#30 /path/html/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php(204): Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->doExecute()
#31 /path/html/administrator/index.php(51): Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()
```